# How to get information about a parent tag through smaller sub-sub tags

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have this code

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.responseType = "document";
            request.overrideMimeType("text/html");
            const xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
        <places>
           <store>
             <coordinates>x, y</coordinates>
             <name>store1</name>
             <stock>
               <item>
                 <itemname>tshirt</itemname>
                 <instock>5</instock>
               </item>
             </stock>
           </store>
         </places>'
```

Edit: I felt my first question wasn't really clear, so here I go again:
I want to get use elements in the `itemname` tag to search in the this XML and return the store information like the name and coordinates and assign them both to variables I could use further down my code using JavaScript. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by calling API each time whenver a key is pressed a event will be fired Ex- onkeypress=myFunction() and call your API inside your function and show the response below your search bar this is also called elastic searh